# How to make a display port cable provide max resolution for Dell U2713HM with Mac Book Pro?

Tags: macos, display

I bought [This Display Port Cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004CAGDUA) to use with Mac Book Pro OSX 10.9.X and Dell U2713HM monitor supporting resolution 2560X1440.  The cable is giving me only 1080p resolution.  I have restarted both the monitor and the laptop.  I tried to google and find anything additional I need to install, but havent found anything.  So what is missing here and what do I need to get the max resolution?  I looked on the dell support for anything for osx but no drivers found.  I'm new to the apple world and I'm assuming here that you dont really install drivers for it?  So what do I need to do?

Comment: Some new things I found - Actually I have 2 monitors hooked from the macbookpro.  One supports max of 1080p and the other (mentioned above) supports max of 2560X1440.  If I hookup only U2713 to the mac, I DO GET full resolution.  But the moment I hook up this other monitor, I only get 1080p.  So it something to do with multiple monitors with different resolutions and the OSX seems to settle with the most max common between both monitors.  Configuring them independently didnt help.